# Is it beneficial or detrimental to delete and re-add Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines, technical-seo

My site was running well, suddenly the site had some server related issues due to which the search visitors of the site decreased from 22 November 2023. This has gone down and now I can't recover it. In the meantime I have changed my server, changed the theme of the site. My site is powered by WordPress. All in all I am experiencing major problems, now I have decided to delete the site's search console and set it up anew.

So I want advice on how to do it better?

Below picture for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your search console has nothing to do with the impact to your website's organic search traffic, it merely reports on it.

It would seem your site was hit by the November core update.
https://www.semrush.com/blog/the-impact-of-the-november-core-update/

How to recover your performance depends on exactly why Google decided your site shouldn't appear in the search results as prominently as it did. Google have published advice on this:

https://developers.google.com/search/updates/core-updates